# Can the verb "start doing something" be used in the present continuous?

Tags: verbs, present-tense, infinitive-vs-gerund, present-continuous

Is it correct to say:

> In this picture, she is starting taking pictures of her friends.

to comment on a picture we are looking at and describing?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. A grammatical rule called "the doubl-_ing_ constraint" blocks some verbs that permit participial clauses as complement from occurring themselves in the participle form. So we can't have *"starting taking", *"needing mowing", and a few others. The obvious verbs concerned are aspectual verbs such as like "begin", "cease", "continue", "start", "stop", and verbs taking concealed passives like "need".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incorrect. You need to avoid using two -ing forms as the structure of the sentence becomes too complex. Instead, I would use *starts taking pictures* or maybe *starts to take pictures*.

Where I use the present simple tense correctly because it is often used as commentary.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would say instead:

> In this picture, she is starting to take pictures of her friends.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your answer is correct.I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Start can be used in the progressive  forms The engine is starting.

> **In this picture, she is starting to take pictures of her friends**

or

> **In this picture, she has started taking pictures of her friends**.

I think the above sentences are correct.